# Shortcut to change keyboard language on XFCE without having to click on xfce-panel plugin

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xfce

I have a Xubuntu 20.04. I added the *Keyboard Layouts* applet plugin to my xfce-panel. To change the keyboard language, I can click on it.

However, I want to be faster. I'd like to press a key combination (shortcut) so that I don't need to click on that all the time.

1. Is there a built-in shortcut to do so?
2. If not, is there a command I can execute? So that I can create a custom keyboard shortcut that runs this command.

My languages are Portuguese (Brazil) and English (US, intl., with dead keys).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the layout tab of Keyboard settings, the shortcut key can be set in the Change layout option combobox.

[image]